# css nth-child nth-last-of-type with javascript – without jquery

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

is there a possibility to appeal (without jquery) with just pure javascript to nth-child() and nth-last-of-type()? I want to largely avoid the use of jquery.

Comment: You can use some CSS3 selectors with `document.querySelectorAll` in modern browsers.

Comment: what are you actually looking to achieve? This question is a bit ambiguous

Comment: select the child elements, store them in an array and select the [4], it's how works jQuery.

Comment: I'm working on a minimal script. The instructions of the client is: no additional librarys and it must work with old browsers (ie7, ie8, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

For example

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(5)');
```

---

## document.querySelectorAll

> **Summary**
>
> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first
> pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified
> group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
>
> where
>
> **elementList** is a non-live NodeList of element objects.
>
> **selectors** is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.
>
> The returned NodeList will contain all the elements in the document
> that are matched by any of the specified selectors. If the selectors
> string contains a CSS pseudo-element, the returned elementList will be
> empty.

Comment: basically it works in advanced browsers, but unfortunately it does not work with ie7!

Comment: @user1154112 Do what I do and stop supporting IE 7 specifically. It's being used at less than 1% of the workstations.

Comment: I have long stopped doing to support ie7, but my client currently has more hits than 8% ie7 :(

Comment: Okay. My condolences.

Answer (score 0):

[This should help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName). You can use this to get the element you desire by class name. You could also .getElementById if no class is present.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[index#];
```

See it work here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r42v7y5L/)

Comment: while this might work but you're not explaining anything about your answer, which doesn't help anyone reading it.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. I've updated the post to include context and example.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS **:last-child** Selector

The **:last-child** selector matches **every element** that is the **last child of its parent**.

For example

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div:last-child');

console.log(elements);

// example output
// NodeList(32)[div.container, div, div, ...]
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp